# Map a key value to the other values in the data

Tags: angular, typescript, list, dictionary, collections

Suppose I have data coming as json in the below format

```
[
    {
        "clauseId": 1,
        "clauseName": "cover",
        "texts": [
            {
                "textId": 1,
                "text": "hello"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "clauseId": 3,
        "clauseName": "xyz",
        "texts": [
            {
                "textId": 3,
                "text": "hello Everyone"
            },
            {
                "textId": 4,
                "text": "Some data"
            }
        ]
    }
 {
        "clauseId": 2,
        "clauseName": "joining",
        "texts": [
            {
                "textId": 3,
                "text": "hello1"
            },
            {
                "textId": 4,
                "text": "hello2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have made a list from clause Name like

```
c=[joining,xyz]
```

I want to make a list where the text is coming like

```
d=[hello Everyone,Some data,hello1,hello2]
```

Please suggest something about it

Comment: Check the modified answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gedgr9?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
result = [];

constructor() {
  let texts:any[] = this.data.filter(item => this.c.includes(item.clauseName)).sort((a, b) => a.clauseId - b.clauseId).flatMap(x => x.texts);

  this.result = texts.map(x => x.text);
}
```

Comment: What if I change the index of c=[xyz,joining]..The answer remains the same,,That is not the thing I want.Please have a look..@Adrita Sharma

Comment: What if there are multiple values in c

Answer (score 1):

You can filter and then get desired fields:

```
let filters = ['hello Everyone','Some data','hello1','hello2'];
const result = arr.filter(f => 
    f.texts.some(s => filters.includes(s.text)))
                  .map(a => a.clauseName);
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
      "clauseId": 1,
      "clauseName": "cover",
      "texts": [
          {
              "textId": 1,
              "text": "hello"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "clauseId": 3,
      "clauseName": "xyz",
      "texts": [
          {
              "textId": 3,
              "text": "hello Everyone"
          },
          {
              "textId": 4,
              "text": "Some data"
          }
      ]
  },
{
      "clauseId": 2,
      "clauseName": "joining",
      "texts": [
          {
              "textId": 3,
              "text": "hello1"
          },
          {
              "textId": 4,
              "text": "hello2"
          }
      ]
  }
]

let filters = ['hello Everyone','Some data','hello1','hello2'];
const result = arr.filter(f=> f.texts.some(s => filters.includes(s.text))).map(a=>a.clauseName);
console.log(result);
```

**UPDATE 1:**

If you want to filter by `['joining','xyz'];`, then you can use `filters` array and check whether data is contained by `includes` method:

```
let filters = ['joining','xyz'];
const result = arr.filter(f => filters.includes(f.clauseName))
                  .flatMap(r => r.texts.map(t => t.text));
console.log(result);
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
      "clauseId": 1,
      "clauseName": "cover",
      "texts": [
          {
              "textId": 1,
              "text": "hello"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "clauseId": 3,
      "clauseName": "xyz",
      "texts": [
          {
              "textId": 3,
              "text": "hello Everyone"
          },
          {
              "textId": 4,
              "text": "Some data"
          }
      ]
  },
{
      "clauseId": 2,
      "clauseName": "joining",
      "texts": [
          {
              "textId": 3,
              "text": "hello1"
          },
          {
              "textId": 4,
              "text": "hello2"
          }
      ]
  }
]

let filters = ['joining','xyz'];
const result = arr.filter(f => filters.includes(f.clauseName))
                  .sort((a,b) => a.clauseId - b.clauseId)
                  .flatMap(r => r.texts.map(t => t.text));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Its the other way round,I have a list of clauseName,I want to map it to the text,like in this case  let filters = ['joining','xyz'];@StepUp

Comment: Well thankYou but the problem is that if  I change the pattern of filters=['xyz','joining']      Answer remains the same but I require itr to change it into   [hello1,hello2,helloEveryone,Somedata]

Comment: @adityamishra so try to use the first version of my reply

Comment: No the above anser is correct please suggest me an idead that if I take  filters=[xyz,joining] the result comes as [hello1,hello2,helloEveryone,Somedata],and if I change filters=[joining,xyz] the result comes as [
  "hello Everyone",
  "Some data",
  "hello1",
  "hello2"
] @StepUp

Comment: What iof there are multiple values in filters

Comment: @adityamishra As a good practice at stckoverflow is one question per post. 
So if you want to make some custom sorting, then feel free to create another post with clear conditions of sorting.
If you feel that my reply helpful, then [what should I do when someone answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)