# I have a data and want to map all the elements to other elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, list

```
[
    {
        "clauseId": 1,
        "clauseName": "cover",
        "texts": [
            {
                "textId": 1,
                "text": "hello"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "clauseId": 3,
        "clauseName": "xyz",
        "texts": [
            {
                "textId": 3,
                "text": "hello Everyone"
            },
            {
                "textId": 4,
                "text": "Some data"
            }
        ]
    }
 {
        "clauseId": 2,
        "clauseName": "joining",
        "texts": [
            {
                "textId": 3,
                "text": "hello1"
            },
            {
                "textId": 4,
                "text": "hello2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

If I make a list like

```
a=[joining,cover]
```

I want  a new list to be formed as

```
b=[hello1,hello2,hello]
```

Please note that index of every element matters If i reverse the index the

```
b =[hello,hello1,hello2]
```

If

```
a=[xyz,joining,cover]
b=["hello Everyone","Some data",hello1,hello2,hello]
```

Similary If I interchange the places in a like `[joining,xyz,cover]`

```
b=["hello1","hello2","hello Everyone","Some data",hello]
```

Please note that the incoming data can have multiple clauseName and multiple texts in it..This is just a demo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Map a key value to the other values in the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59065977/map-a-key-value-to-the-other-values-in-the-data)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a look up table from your original array by using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). The map will use each `clauseName` as the key and point to an array of texts as the value. You can then `.flatMap()` your clauses array to values at each key in your look up table (ie the `Map`).

See example below:

```js
const arr=[{clauseId:1,clauseName:"cover",texts:[{textId:1,text:"hello"}]},{clauseId:3,clauseName:"xyz",texts:[{textId:3,text:"hello Everyone"},{textId:4,text:"Some data"}]},{clauseId:2,clauseName:"joining",texts:[{textId:3,text:"hello1"},{textId:4,text:"hello2"}]}];

const clauses = ["joining", "cover"];
const lut = new Map(arr.map(({clauseName, texts}) => 
  [clauseName, texts.map(({text}) => text)]
));

const result = clauses.flatMap(key => lut.get(key));
console.log(result);
```

If you cannot use JS's native `.flatMap` implementation you can either polyfill it or use [lodash](https://lodash.com/)'s implementation:

```js
const arr = [{clauseId:1,clauseName:"cover",texts:[{textId:1,text:"hello"}]},{clauseId:3,clauseName:"xyz",texts:[{textId:3,text:"hello Everyone"},{textId:4,text:"Some data"}]},{clauseId:2,clauseName:"joining",texts:[{textId:3,text:"hello1"},{textId:4,text:"hello2"}]}];

const clauses = ["joining", "cover"];
const lut = new Map(arr.map(({clauseName, texts}) => 
  [clauseName, texts.map(({text}) => text)]
));

const result = _.flatMap(clauses, key => lut.get(key));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is an error coming as flatmap doesnot exist on the data type string@Nick Parsons

Comment: In the example, I am using `.flatMap` on an array, double-check that you are using `.flatMap` on an array (it sounds like you're trying to call it on a string)

Comment: I checked it it showing the same error@Nick Parsons

Comment: @adityamishra It's hard to tell what the issue is without seeing how you're trying to use it. The only thing I can think of is that you're using a browser that doesn't support `.flatMap()` (however, I would expect a different error to appear if that was the case). If you're browser doesn't support `.flatMap()`, you can use lodashes `_.flatMap()` (which I believe you have access to as you're using angular - if not you can always install it). I've updated my answer to include a code snippet using lodashes version of `_.flatMap()`

Comment: Thanks @Nick Parsons..Just had to update lib in ts.config.json